# Could AWS Lambda spin up 2 instances of a lambda on a single request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency

I am experiencing a problem in my company's production environment. We have an API Gateway endpoint that triggers a lambda to process some data. It appears that we made 1 gateway request and Lambda tried to process it with 2 different instances of the lambda. i.e. it processed all the records twice. There are 2 request IDs which I think come from the API Gateway itself, but I don't know for sure.

My understanding is that lambdas only scale on additional requests. Is it possible that a single large request could have spun up two instances which both tried to process the data?

I need an authoritative answer.

Comment: Is it possible that [MaximumRetryAttempts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventinvokeconfig.html) is set to 1 and the lambda failed after processing the records but before completing?

Comment: Maximum retry attempts is set to 2. I'm leaning towards this being caused by retries, but I just can't tell. Thanks for your response.

Comment: It's worth checking the CloudWatch log timestamps for the two lambda calls: were they ever running concurrently? It could help to share redacted logs for the lambda and API Gateway, is there any indication that one of the lambda calls failed/didn't succeed?